# Is main activity mainly used as a bridge to separate classes and activities?

Tags: java, android, main-activity

Lets say you've made a messaging app. The main activity would present different contacts and give you options for sharing, messaging, voice-calling, etc. Would each of those options have separate classes all stemming from the main activity class file? If so, would linking those classes into main activity be as easy as creating a method stub in the main activity to open those activities/classes for each option pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's a good idea to use only one Activity for your Application.

Because in android an activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user.

I suppose that for options you want to have a different UI and different user interaction.
So i think that you should use multiple activity's for you options.

To find more information about Activity's check the link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Ok. Use different activities for different UIs. I understand. Still all of the different activities must link to MainActivity correct?

Comment: @officialasim, I don't uderstand the question.
If you want to know how to start one activity from another activity, see the topic "Starting Activities and Getting Results" by the link above.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities